# Demonstrate determinant of a matrix with all its elements $\pm 1$ is an even number

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm asked to prove the following statement:

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix ($n\geq 2$) with all its elements being either $+1$ or $-1$. Check that its determinant is an even number (i.e. $det(A)=\pm 2k$, with $k$ being an integer number).

I'm not too sure how should I approach this problem. I don't even know where to start the proof, but a hint or two would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Note:** My professor showed how this property holds for several matrices $A$ she wrote down in the blackboard, but never gave a full mathematical demonstration. This is not an exercise or something, it's simply curiosity. I've used all my (very limited) Algebra knowledge to no avail. No demonstrations found on the internet. I asked for some help here, but I think I'll just go and ask her during tutoring hours.

Comment: Corrected the question

Comment: Is it $2^k$ or $2k$?

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: It is definitely 2k - not only because of the even in the title but also because of easy examples like the 'all 1' matrix with determinant 0

Comment: It's $2k$ with k being an integer, sorry for the confusion. I corrected it.

Comment: Also, the last example shows that the condition $k \neq 0$ should be omited (of course it made some sense when the $k$ was still in the exponent)

Comment: @B.Pasternak I'm kinda new to algebra, so my toolset is very limited. I don't know if I'd be able to solve this advanced problem using only what I've learned from class.

Comment: I think what B.Pasternak is getting at is this: how do you normally compute determinants: do you perhaps express them as a sum of smaller determinants and their negatives?

Comment: I usually use adjoints to compute the determinant of a matrix, but I'm not too sure how can I draw a general conclusion using only adjoints.

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction is useful. Indeed, as @Vincent says, expressing your determinant as as sum of smaller determinants is what I'm hinting at. You can easily do the $n=2$ case, and then use induction and this procedure to do the general case (although I'm not entirely sure what Vincent means with "their negatives"). The new answer below is a nice shortcut, though.

Comment: @B.Pasternak Well, if you compute a determinant using Laplace expansion (is that what it is called?) then some of the 'small' determinants in the sum are multiplied with -1 before being added to the others. So it is not just a sum, but an alternating sum.

Comment: @Vincent That's indeed what I thought you meant.

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by using adjoints to compute the determinant? It does not seem obvious to me how one would do that

Comment: @Vincent Sorry, I meant minors (not adjoints). So I generally manipulate the determinant so that it simplifies a bit. Then I conveniently pick a cofactor and a minor. That's how I generally compute a determinant.

Comment: Well, then we are talking about the same thing and induction would work... But I like the other answers.

Comment: I'd like to see how induction would work here, since the $+1$ and $-1$ are scattered randomly on the initial matrix $A$. It would be easy to prove it for $n=2$, then $n=3$, but I would have big troubles trying to imply from there how it would work for a more general $n$ (previously proving that the determinant of $A \in M^{(n-1)\times (n-1)}$ is even, which also seems also difficult). If you are able to find this result using induction, I'd love to see the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the definition, we see that
\begin{align}
\det A \mod 2\equiv \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) a_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}\mod 2 \equiv \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} 1 \mod 2  \equiv 0 \mod 2. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what does the symbol $\sigma$ represent?

Comment: $S_n$ is the set of permutation of $n$ elements. For example $n = 3$, the function $\sigma(1) = 2, \sigma(2) = 3, \sigma(3) = 1$ is an example of a permutation.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't know I could apply the $mod$ operand on matrices too, I found this answer very interesting. Thank you for your time !

Comment: Just to make it clear, I applied mod to a number $\det A$.

Answer (score 3):

If one add the $1^{st}$ column of $A$ to the $2^{nd}$, $3^{th}, \cdots, n^{th}$ columns, we obtain a determinant $A'$ whose entries in $2^{nd}$ to $n^{th}$ columns are all even integers. Extract the $n-1$ copies of $2$ from these columns, we can express
$\det(A)$ as  $2^{n-1} \det(A'')$ for another matrix $A''$ with integer coefficients.

As a result, $\det(A)$ is not only even, it is divisible by $2^{n-1}$.